# Matrix of percentages of values to the sum of values grouped by a column's criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix of values and need to get their shares to the sum of a respective group.

Example:

[image]

Need to get - a matrix of percentages of each id within a class to a total of class/region
[image]

I was trying the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id_1', 'id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6','id_7','id_8','id_9'],
               'region':['reg_1','reg_1','reg_1','reg_2','reg_2','reg_2','reg_3','reg_3','reg_3'],
               'class_1':[5,8,2,5,5,4,6,5,3],
               'class_2':[6,8,3,7,8,5,8,6,4],
               'class_3':[7,8,4,4,3,6,7,9,8,]})
cols=list(df.iloc[:,2:].columns)
weights=df.iloc[:,2:].div(df.groupby(['region'])[cols].sum())
```

It doesn't work..

I took a matrix of sums in region/class

```
sum=df.set_index('id').groupby(['region']).sum()
```

but I do not know how to divide matrices of different sizes then..

Please, can anybody help? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex`, so possible use parameter `level` in [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
cols = df.columns[2:]
df1 = df.groupby(['region'])[cols].sum()
#another solution
#df1 = df.iloc[:,2:].groupby(df['region']).sum()
weights=df.set_index(['id','region']).div(df1, level='region').reset_index()
print (weights)
     id region   class_1   class_2   class_3
0  id_1  reg_1  0.333333  0.352941  0.368421
1  id_2  reg_1  0.533333  0.470588  0.421053
2  id_3  reg_1  0.133333  0.176471  0.210526
3  id_4  reg_2  0.357143  0.350000  0.307692
4  id_5  reg_2  0.357143  0.400000  0.230769
5  id_6  reg_2  0.285714  0.250000  0.461538
6  id_7  reg_3  0.428571  0.444444  0.291667
7  id_8  reg_3  0.357143  0.333333  0.375000
8  id_9  reg_3  0.214286  0.222222  0.333333
```

Or create `Multiindex` first, so possible use `sum` with `level` parameter too:

```
df1=df.set_index(['id','region'])
weights = df1.div(df1.sum(level='region'), level='region').reset_index()
print (weights)
     id region   class_1   class_2   class_3
0  id_1  reg_1  0.333333  0.352941  0.368421
1  id_2  reg_1  0.533333  0.470588  0.421053
2  id_3  reg_1  0.133333  0.176471  0.210526
3  id_4  reg_2  0.357143  0.350000  0.307692
4  id_5  reg_2  0.357143  0.400000  0.230769
5  id_6  reg_2  0.285714  0.250000  0.461538
6  id_7  reg_3  0.428571  0.444444  0.291667
7  id_8  reg_3  0.357143  0.333333  0.375000
8  id_9  reg_3  0.214286  0.222222  0.333333
```

Another idea is filter columns by positions, use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `DataFrame` with same size like original, so possible divide and assign back:

```
cols = df.columns[2:]
df[cols] = df[cols].div(df.groupby('region')[cols].transform('sum'))
print (df)
     id region   class_1   class_2   class_3
0  id_1  reg_1  0.333333  0.352941  0.368421
1  id_2  reg_1  0.533333  0.470588  0.421053
2  id_3  reg_1  0.133333  0.176471  0.210526
3  id_4  reg_2  0.357143  0.350000  0.307692
4  id_5  reg_2  0.357143  0.400000  0.230769
5  id_6  reg_2  0.285714  0.250000  0.461538
6  id_7  reg_3  0.428571  0.444444  0.291667
7  id_8  reg_3  0.357143  0.333333  0.375000
8  id_9  reg_3  0.214286  0.222222  0.333333
```

EDIT:

`Performance` for @Brendam Cox:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000
L = list('abcdefghijklmno')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(N*len(L)),
                   'region': np.repeat(L, N)})

df = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(N*len(L), 5))).add_prefix('class_'))

print (df)
```

---

```
In [349]: %%timeit
     ...: cols = df.columns[2:]
     ...: df1 = df.groupby(['region'])[cols].sum()
     ...: #another solution
     ...: #df1 = df.iloc[:,2:].groupby(df['region']).sum()
     ...: weights=df.set_index(['id','region']).div(df1, level='region').reset_index()
     ...: 
     ...: 
13.9 ms ± 227 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [350]: %%timeit
     ...: df1=df.set_index(['id','region'])
     ...: weights = df1.div(df1.sum(level='region'), level='region').reset_index()
     ...: 
13.8 ms ± 595 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [351]: %%timeit
     ...: cols = df.columns[2:]
     ...: df[cols] = df[cols].div(df.groupby('region')[cols].transform('sum'))
     ...: 
8.99 ms ± 602 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [352]: %%timeit
     ...: (df.set_index(['id','region'])
     ...:    .groupby('region')
     ...:    .apply(lambda x: x/x.sum()
     ...:    )
     ...: )
     ...: 
49.5 ms ± 428 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: `groupby` and `transform` was my (deleted; always too slow...) answer, but I am not experienced enough to understand the rationale for selecting between these approaches, and `DataFrame.div` is new to me. Can you comment on the efficiency of these different methods?

Comment: @BrendanCox - timings in groupby are not easy, because need random new df, but I try it.

Comment: @jezrael Thank you very much. All solutions are workable and clear. I would not have guessed by myself to use multIndex and level. Wonderful!

Comment: @jezrael, for the real data the code returns error that i do not know how to interpret: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. What can be wrong in the original data?

Comment: it must be due to diff type of data. That is: df is dtypes: object(313) and df1 is dtypes: float64(299), int64(12). How can I adjust code to align data types?

Comment: I use this: cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['float']).columns

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='float', errors='coerce')

Comment: Got a weight matrix! Great

Answer (score 0):

An apply would work as well:

```
(df.set_index(['id','region'])
   .groupby('region')
   .apply(lambda x: x/x.sum())
)
```

output:

```
              class_1   class_2   class_3
id   region                              
id_1 reg_1   0.333333  0.352941  0.368421
id_2 reg_1   0.533333  0.470588  0.421053
id_3 reg_1   0.133333  0.176471  0.210526
id_4 reg_2   0.357143  0.350000  0.307692
id_5 reg_2   0.357143  0.400000  0.230769
id_6 reg_2   0.285714  0.250000  0.461538
id_7 reg_3   0.428571  0.444444  0.291667
id_8 reg_3   0.357143  0.333333  0.375000
id_9 reg_3   0.214286  0.222222  0.333333
```